# When was <input type=search> introduced in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, html

When was `<input type=search.>` (and `type=range` etc.) introduced in Safari?
And can you find the blog-post to this item? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be proposed since [July, 2004](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/hyatt/archives/2004_07.html#005938)... but if you are asking about Safari support is [available in Safari 2.0 and later](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html).